# Different results for the same command in shell

Tags: linux, bash

```
for file in `ls nmm-*.txt`; do 
    awk -v fn="${file}" 'function abs(x){return ((x<0.0)?-x:x)} {if(NR>1 &&(abs($1)>4096 || abs($2)>4096)) print fn" "NR;}' ${file}
done
```

When I run this command in shell, I get errors:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `nmm-990000.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

But if I put the same command in a file like ttt and

```
chmod +x ddd ; ./ddd
```

it works.

Here is a similar question:

```
ls nmm-*.txt | sort -k1.4n
```

This command will not give correct results if I run it in shell. but if I use it in a shell script, it works. I am using bash.

Any suggestion?

Comment: here are the result:alias l.='ls -d .*'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls --color'

Comment: Do you use the same shell interactively and for running the script? What is your login shell? How do you run the script?

Comment: Yes, I use the same shell which is bash.

Comment: Check your environment. Run 'env' command in shell and inside script and compare the outputs. Recommendations: instead of `ls nmm-*.txt`  simply use: for file in nmm-*.txt; ... Do not use the ls-Command to feed command pipes. Use sort -k1.4n file1 file2 ... Avoid to use 'file' as a variable name.

Comment: I run 'evn' as you said. if I run the script as ". ddd"(there is only one command of env in ddd), the results are the same with in shell. If "./ddd", there is no OLDPWD, SHLVL=2 not 1 and another line of _=/bin/env. Others are the same.

Comment: I tried to use "for fname in nmm-*.txt;" this one works. Thank you. But I have hundreds of files, sort -k1.4n file1 fiel2... is no possible.

Answer (score 0):

As zb' suspected, the malfunction is due to the alias (which is only expanded in an interactive shell) of `ls` with option `--color`; when using that output, the color control codes are wrapped around the file name, and this conglomerate is neither usable as a file name to open nor sorted as one might expect.

As suggested, this can be avoided by using `for fname in nmm-*.txt` without invoking `ls`, also by using `/bin/ls nmm-*.txt | …` (that way, no alias will be expanded). You may also consider dropping the `alias ls=…`.